# Jquery dlmenu animation is not smooth

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I have created multilevel navigation menu using [jquery dlmenu plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Responsive-Multi-Level-Menu-Plugin-Dlmenu/index2.html) v1.0.2 demo2.

Everything works fine, except CSS3 menu navigation is not smooth as jQuery left/right slide functionality is.

Is there any solution to resolve this issue without changing plugin?

```
/* Animation classes for moving out and in */

.dl-menu.dl-animate-out-2 {
    -webkit-animation: MenuAnimOut2 0.3s ease-in-out forwards;
    -moz-animation: MenuAnimOut2 0.3s ease-in-out forwards;
    animation: MenuAnimOut2 0.3s ease-in-out forwards;    
}
@-webkit-keyframes MenuAnimOut2 {
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes MenuAnimOut2 {
    100% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes MenuAnimOut2 {
    100% {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

.dl-menu.dl-animate-in-2 {
    -webkit-animation: MenuAnimIn2 0.3s ease-in-out forwards;
    -moz-animation: MenuAnimIn2 0.3s ease-in-out forwards;
    animation: MenuAnimIn2 0.3s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes MenuAnimIn2 {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes MenuAnimIn2 {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(0px);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes MenuAnimIn2 {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(0px);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle ?

Comment: jsfiddle link is :  http://jsfiddle.net/L4djyszr/2/

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the plugin like this : with animationClasses "in" and "out" not "classin" and "classout"

```
$(function() {
  $( '#dl-menu' ).dlmenu({
    animationClasses : { in : 'dl-animate-in-2', out : 'dl-animate-out-2' }
  });
});
```

Comment: I have already used these class, check jsfiddle once. in animation flickering is there , slide left and slide right animation is not smooth.

Comment: I don't understand what you need. What do you mean by "not smooth" ? What is your browser ?

Comment: So if you want a slide effect, take a look at my answer and replace "classin" and "classout" with "in" and "out". Look at the plugin code in your fiddle [http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Responsive-Multi-Level-Menu-Plugin-Dlmenu/js/jquery.dlmenu.js](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Responsive-Multi-Level-Menu-Plugin-Dlmenu/js/jquery.dlmenu.js) there is no classes "classin" and "classout"  in animationClasses options. This is why you have the default demo-1 animation.

Comment: Sir, I have provided you only reference of that example not implement in my code, Please compare demo 2 & jquery animation.... you can clearly see that jquery slidding & css animation difference. I have change animation time in css (e.g. dlmenu.css -webkit-animation) as well but at the end of animation fade in fade out effect.